# How to set tabindex on panelTabSet in ICEfaces

Tags: jsf, icefaces

How can I specify the tabindex of a panelTabSet? I have tried setting it on the both the panelTabSet:

```
<ice:panelTabSet id="foo" tabindex="4"> ...
```

and on the panelTabs

```
<ice:panelTab id="bar" tabindex="4"> ...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this is not supported in the 1.8.2 version of ICEfaces. ICEsoft has registered a JIRA on it, and hopefully it will be solved in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [panelTab TLD](http://www.icefaces.org/docs/latest/tld/ice/panelTab.html), there is no such attribute. The index of the tabs inside a panelTabSet is defined by the position in the source.

```
<ice:panelTabSet selectedIndex="2">
    <ice:panelTab label="first tab">...</ice:panelTab>
    <ice:panelTab label="second tab">...</ice:panelTab>
    <ice:panelTab label="third tab">...</ice:panelTab>
</ice:panelTabSet>
```

In the above example, the "third tab" is selected by default (index starts at 0)

Comment: Tanks, but that does not solve my problem. Let me rephrase: I have an application where the user can navigate by using the keyboard. E.g. pressing the [TAB]-key brings focus from one field to the next (in the tab-sequence). But the panelTabSet is not part of said sequence. So - how can the user get from a text-field to the first selected panelTab - the customers requirement is that this must be possible by using the [TAB]-key. Is it? 

One more thing - I have to specify tabindex on the other components in the web-page since "natural" tab order is not sufficient for the customers needs.

Comment: I think this is not possible in ICEfaces, at least not as simple as setting an attribute.

Maybe you could write some JavaScript, that invokes the click event on the given tab, when the user presses a key.